# Permissions issue in eclipse

Tags: permissions, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Indigo in Ubuntu 12.04.3. I checked out a project from subversion and put it in my workspace. When I try to run Main.CPP (it's a C++ project -- not java), I get the following error message:

> ```
> Exception occurred executing command line.
> Cannot run program "/home/abramhandler/workspace/tux/main.cpp" (in directory   "/home/abramhandler/workspace/tux"): java.io.IOException:
> ```
>
> error=13, Permission denied

How can I give Eclipse permission to run things in this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to give Eclipse permission to run things in that folder; it already has that permission. The **Permission denied** error is due to the shell refusing to execute `main.cpp` because the file doesn't have its execute permission bits set. Which makes sense because you don't execute **cpp** files.

Comment: great. that explains a lot. I am new to C++ development in eclipse. Now I know that I made a mistake in the build configurations.